# Is it (now) possible to print multiple copies with window.print()

Tags: javascript, printing

I need to print receipts in my web app for my users. 
So far so good.
But I also need to print a copy of the receipt which is in every way in the same format as the first receipt. That's why I'd like to set the number of copies to 2.

Through my research, I came to realize that it's not possible through JavaScript but all the post I read were very old.

I tried to call my function twice in a Chrome browser set to kiosk mode like this:

```
public printCoupon(): void {
    const mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=200px,width=200px');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body style="width:300px;height:200px">');
    mywindow.document.write('<div style="width: 100%;display: flex;justify-content: space-between; flex-direction: row;">');
    // ...
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();


    public print(): void {
        let numberOfCouponsToPrint = 2;
        while (numberOfCouponsToPrint > 0) {
          this.printCoupon();
          numberOfCouponsToPrint--;
        }
```

But without success.

If I missed something or you know any workaround, please let me know.

Comment: Can't you just repeat the data multiple times and put a page break?

Comment: Printing requires the user to confirm by clicking inside the printing options screen so a loop is suboptimal. Try pasting the text twice inside the print window you create with a page break set between the two recipes.

Comment: Also, you're missing a closing brace, but not sure where you put it, cause it can also cause issues in your code.